# How to use SELECT in sqlcommand

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables

Table payment:

```
 paymentid   orderid{FK_payment_orderlist}    totalprice   datetime   status  RefID   SaleReferenceId
```

Table orderlist:

```
orderid    customerid   classid
```

I have a StoredProcedure like this :

```
USE [miztahrirtest2]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertPayment]    Script Date: 8/19/2015 8:51:08 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[InsertPayment] @orderid int,@totalprice int,@status nvarchar(50),@new_identity    INT    OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    insert into payment(orderid,totalprice,[datetime],[status],RefID,SaleReferenceId) SELECT MAX(orderid) FROM orderlist As orderid,values(@orderid,@totalprice,GETDATE(),@status,'','')
    SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    SELECT @new_identity AS id
    return @new_identity
END
```

I want to choose last `orderid` from `orderlist` table and set in with another values into `payment` table but that code doesn't work correctly .What should i do now?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the orderid field as [identity](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), so it will be automatically handled and you should remove it from the insert statement. Then you can use the scope_identity() to get the id value that the row you inserted got.

So the insert statement should look something like this:

```
insert into payment(totalprice,[datetime],[status],RefID,SaleReferenceId) 
values(@totalprice,GETDATE(),@status,'','')
```

Comment: I would not recommend using empty strings ('') for anything, if the value is missing use NULL, and if it's ID, maybe it should be a number instead?

Comment: thanks for that but i don't know how to define it and how to use scope_identity() for that .could you show that to me in with code?

Comment: @mahdi.gh The scope_identity select after the insert was ok, it just needs the identity field and you have to define identity in create table -clause, or use alter table to drop + add the column